# How to Check if a database exists in SQLite?

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite

I am developing a windows phone 8 app using sqlite and am trying to check if the database exists and if it doesnt exist,it should be created. but i keep getting the error message "System.windows.shapes.path does not contain a definition for combine". Is there another way to do it or how can i improve it?

```
public static string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "ContactsManager.sqlite"));//DataBase Name 
    public App()
    {
        if (!CheckFileExists("ContactsManager.sqlite").Result)
        {
            using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
            {
                db.CreateTable<Contacts>();
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Path.Combine is defined in System.IO.Path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Panagiotis Kanavos's comment was right, you have resolved the *Path* class using wrong namespace!

Remove

```
using System.Windows.Shapes; // for silverlite
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes; // for winrt
```

and add

```
using System.IO;
```

Comment: thank you...it worked perfect.. i removed using System.windows.shapes and replaced it with using System.IO

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to check if the database exist? I don't know about windows phone, but in Windows, as soon as you try to add a table into a SQLite database, if the database doesn't exist, it creates it. If you are worried about the table existing already, you can use:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName(...)
```

(I tried to ask it as comment but I don't have the reputation)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a `Path.Combine` in a `Path.Combine`? If `Path.Combine` is not available with one or two parameter, why not simple concat two strings?

You have it 2x: `public static string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "ContactsManager.sqlite"));`

Comment: Path.Combine *does* accept two parameters. It's either a typo or copy pasted code on the OP's part

Comment: It also could be his problem, because the compiler say: `System.windows.shapes.path does not contain a definition for combine` or am i wrong?

Comment: maybe i am blind but the method with one string parameter (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd991142(v=vs.110).aspx) is available since windows phone **8.1**

Comment: Wrong. Path.Combine is in the System.IO.Path class. You probably added the wrong reference

Comment: Yep totally wrong. my fault. i will delete the answer

Comment: DON'T - you found the double Combine! Just edit the answer saying that it's the wrong class

Answer (score 1):

you can check by this:

```
public async Task<bool> isFilePresent(string fileName)
 {
 return System.IO.File.Exists(string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, fileName);
 }
```